# How to calculate pairwise Euclidean distance between a collection of vectors

Tags: python, pandas, distance, series

I have a pandas data frame like this. Where the index is pd.DatetimeIndex and the columns are timeseries.

|  | x_1 | x_2 | x_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-08-17 | 133.23 | 2457.45 | -4676 |
| 2020-08-18 | -982 | -6354.56 | -245.657 |
| 2020-08-19 | 5678.642 | 245.2786 | 2461.785 |
| 2020-08-20 | -2394 | 154.34 | -735.653 |
| 2020-08-20 | 236 | -8876 | -698.245 |

I need to calculate the Euclidean distance of all the columns against each other. I.e., (x_1 - x_2), (x_1 - x_3), (x_2 - x_3), and return a square data frame like this:
(Please realize that the values in this table are just an example and not the actual result of the Euclidean distance)

|  | x_1 | x_2 | x_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x_1 | 0 | 123 | 456 |
| x_2 | 123 | 0 | 789 |
| x_3 | 456 | 789 | 0 |

I tried [this](https://drawingfromdata.com/pandas/clustering/making-a-pairwise-distance-matrix-in-pandas.html) resource but I could not figure out how to pass the columns of my df. If understand correctly the example passes the rows as the series to calculate the ED from.

Comment: The fact you have a DatetimeIndex and the columns are timeseries seems irrelevant. You essentially have 3 points, in n-dimensional space (where n is the number of rows) and you want to calculate the euclidean distance, right?

Comment: Euclidean distance. I know I can do something like np.linalg.norm(x_1 - x_2). But I want to calculate all columns at the same time. The output should look like the second dataframe, although the numbers are just to illustrate how the df should be filled.

Comment: @Riley yes I want the Euclidean distance of all the columns not rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An explicit way of achieving this would be:

```
from itertools import combinations

import numpy as np

dist_df = pd.DataFrame(index=df.columns, columns=df.columns)

for col_a, col_b in combinations(df.columns, 2):
    dist = np.linalg.norm(df[col_a] - df[col_b])
    dist_df.loc[col_a, col_b] = dist
    dist_df.loc[col_b, col_a] = dist

print(dist_df)
```

outputs

```
              x_1           x_2           x_3
x_1           NaN  12381.858429   6135.306973
x_2  12381.858429           NaN  12680.121047
x_3   6135.306973  12680.121047           NaN
```

If you want `0` instead of `NaN` use [`DataFrame.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
dist_df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: This code works but has a bug and I used itertools product instead of combinations. The reason is that combinations only makes pairs of distinct columns. And ED formula also computes cases like x_1 vs x_1.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833780/how-to-use-itertools-to-compute-all-combinations-with-repeating-elements

Comment: @rbrt Not sure I see the bug. This code generates NaNs along the diagonal and later changes them to 0 (which is the expected distance)

Comment: Yes, but by using itertools combinations it never computes x_1 vs x_1. I guess that is why it returns NaN. In fact I used the same logic to calculate Cosine Similarity in the same dataset, which expects 1s in the diagonal and it returns NaN. That's how I noticed something was off, and found that replacing "combinations" with "product" solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will work, with any number of columns.

**setup**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "x1":[133.23, -982, 5678.642, -2394, 236],
        "x2":[2457.45, -6354.56, 245.2786, 154.34, -8876],
        "x3":[-4676, -245.657, 2461.785, -735.653, 698.245],
    }
)
```

**solution**

```
import numpy as np

aux = np.broadcast_to(df.values,  (df.shape[1], *df.shape))
result = np.sqrt(np.square(aux - aux.transpose()).sum(axis=1))
```

`result` is a `numpy.array`

You can wrap it up in a dataframe if you wish like this

```
pd.DataFrame(result, columns=df.columns, index=df.columns)

              x1            x2            x3
x1      0.000000  12381.858429   6081.352512
x2  12381.858429      0.000000  13622.626775
x3   6081.352512  13622.626775      0.000000
```

Why this approach works is beyond what I'm willing to go into and requires a strong math background.  You will need to decide what is more important for you: speed, or readability/understandability.

Comment: *"Why this approach works is beyond what I'm willing to go into and requires a strong math background"* Huh? It almost literally contains the Euclidean distance formula. I'd remove this "fluff" from the answer, especially considering the fact OP already knows about `np.linalg.norm`

Comment: It's involves broadcasting the matrices and calculating the euclidean distance between vectors using 3 dimensional matrices.  It's not trivial.

Comment: This code works! However, I decided not to use it since it is beyond my skills (although I read about broadcast) and I wanted to be able to understand and explain the code.

Comment: You can also check out scipy distance metrics https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.pdist